# Post request fails in Django Rest Framwork due to CSRF Token missing

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I am trying to make a `POST` request to my DRF API Endpoint through a React frontend. I get a `403 Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /api/content/wishlists` error. I looked at other solutions, and most of them point out that the default django authentication classes need to be adapted to DRF.

I am working with django-rest-knox for authentication purposes so my `settings.py` contains:

```
# REST Framework Settings
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',)
}
```

I still keep receiving this error. Here is the api.py

```
class WishlistViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = WishlistSerializer
    queryset = Wishlist.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    ]

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Wishlist.objects.all()
        serializer = WishlistSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Wishlist.objects.all()
        wishlist = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = WishlistSerializer(wishlist)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

My Javascript code to trigger the api call

```
  const createWishlist = (content, setCreated) => {
    axiosInstance
      .post(`/content/wishlists`, content, tokenConfig(auth.token))
      .then((res) => {
        dispatchMessages(createMessage({ contentAdded: "Wishlist created" }));
        setCreated(res.data.id);
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        dispatchErrors(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
      );
  };
```

Where the `tokenConfig` function basically just adds a header with the authentication token to the request like this:

```
export const tokenConfig = (token) => {
  // headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  // IF token add to headers config
  if (token) {
    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
  }

  return config;
};
```

The weird thing is that I am using the same exact code in another application and it is working well. I appreciate any ideas on what could be the issue at hand

Comment: Please check in developer tools if a token is present in the header (that it is not empty). The setup looks ok.

Comment: yes, it's in the request header

Comment: ok, what about `ALLOWED_HOSTS` ?